# Understand type representation in GHC for type checker plugin

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to make a typechecker plugin, and I've got a "null" plugin working (i.e. one that does nothing), but the solver takes three arguments of type `[Ct]`. That's described [here](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/TcRnTypes.html#t:Ct) but what's actually more complex is the subtype `TcType`, which is a type synonym of the type `Type`. The `Type` type is in this module [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc/Type.html), but it's complex, so I was hoping I could work it out by printing out the representation of certain types I create.

I've wrapped my solver in `tracePlugin` from [GHC.TcPluginM.Extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-tcplugins-extra-0.2/docs/GHC-TcPluginM-Extra.html) in attempt to see what's going on, but the output is ugly, and doesn't seem to use the variable names in my program but scrabbled ones.

Any help that will help me understand what's going on will be appreciated.

Comment: could you paste the output?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`Outputable`](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/Outputable.html#t:Outputable) instance of `Type`, or is that the one that is giving you the output you're not satisfied with?